# Remove UItableViewcell selection on displaying UIMenucontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am presenting the menu controller in `UITableView` using these delegates:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0){
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0){

    if(action == @selector(copy:)){
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0){

    if(action == @selector(copy:)){
        NSLog(@"Action");

    }
}
```

The MenuController is showing. but the cell background color changed to `grayColor`.
I don't want to change the cell color. How to do this?? Hoping for a break..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
```

If you're in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` or `performAction: forRowAtIndexPath:` you can more simply replace `[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]` with `indexPath`

If you don't ever want your cell to be selected.. in either `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or in your `UITableViewCell` subclass set `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`

Comment: Thanks a lot..2 days I was behind this for a solution..I tried with xib parameters, making selection to  none,,but didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

To remove CELL selection use this

```
[cell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
```

To remove CELL highlighting use this

```
[cell setHighlighted:NO animated:YES];
```